# css javascript flip animation iphone

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, animation, flip

Why will a flip animation that works fine on a computer not work on an iPhone?

Here is the code, in which `myFunction()` works fine on a PC laptop running Chrome but dies on an iPhone (although an alert can be fired from it)

Astute users may recognize that some of this comes from David Walsh

I hoe it is clear I have used proprietary 'webkit' wherever possible even though I am not convinced this is any longer necessary/ I could provide the html etc if needed  but maybe someone can find a more obvious issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>FLIPPER</title>

<style>
    /* entire container, keeps perspective */

.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;

}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 420px;
    height: 320px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;4

    }

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /// OMG THIS WAS THE WHOLE PROBLEM, 15-18 MAR 2016
    backface-visibility:hidden;             //// OMG NO IT WAS NOT - 31 MAR

    float:left;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    background-color:powderblue;
    padding:10px;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    background-color:yellow;
    padding:10px;
    animation: toFront 0.3s linear normal forwards;

}
.vertical.flip-container {
    position: relative;
}
.vertical.flip-container:active .back {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation: toBack 0.3s linear normal  forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 0px;}
   to {top: 200px;}
} 

@-webkit-keyframes toBack {
  0% {-webkit-z-index:0;z-index:0;}
  100% {-webkit-z-index:0;z-index:1;}//was 1
}
@-webkit-keyframes toFront {
  0% {-webkit-z-index:1;z-index:1;}//was 1
  100% {-webkit-z-index:0;z-index:0;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: 200px;}
} 

@keyframes toBack {
  0% {-webkit-z-index:0;z-index:0;} //was 0
  100% {-webkit-z-index:1;z-index:1;} //was 1
}
@keyframes toFront {
  0% {-webkit-z-index:1;z-index:1;} //was 1
  100% {-webkit-z-index:0;z-index:0;} //was 0
}

.vertical.flip-container .flipper {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 160px;
    transform-origin: 100% 160px; /* half of height */
}

.vertical.flip-container:active .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

vertical.flip-container:active .flipper, .flip-container.active .flipper, .flip-container.flip .flipper
{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);

}


</style>

<script>
function myFunction() {
// PHONE GETS THIS FAR alert ('ok');
document.querySelector('.vertical.flip-container').classList.toggle('active');
}

</script>
</pre>
```

ETC...

Comment: Please add your HTML

Comment: The html simply calls the finction from an onclick (touchstart is no different)
<table align=center>

<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><IMG src=arrows/cursor-up.png height=59 width=61 onclick="myFunction();"></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr><td><IMG src=arrows/cursor-left.png height=59 width=61 onclick="javascript:i--;loadQ();"></td>

<td><IMG src=arrows/cursor-down.png height=59 width=61 onclick="myFunction();"></td>

<td><IMG src=arrows/cursor-right.png height=59 width=61 onclick="javascript:i++;loadQ();"></td></tr>

</table>

Comment: The whole thing can be sourced here although just a skeleton since unfed by any data:

http://www.lextutor.ca/flipper/

Comment: @ThomasCobb that appears to be a dead link